# how to close hamburger menu after click open

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have hamburger menu and added click to open a sub menu and after that struggling to close the sub-menu, please check the detailed code below. Thanks...!!

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("mob").style.display = "inline-flex";
  document.getElementById("mob").style.position = "absolute";
}
```

```css
.hamburger {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #f7941e;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

.mobile-menu {
  display: none;
}

.hamburger-container {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-navbar">
  <div class="hamburger-container" onclick="myFunction()">
    <div class="hamburger"></div>
    <div class="hamburger"></div>
    <div class="hamburger"></div>
    <div class="mobile-menu" id="mob">
      <ul class="mobile-menu-container">
        <li class="mobile-menu-items">Home</li>
        <li class="mobile-menu-items">Types Tours
          <div class="mobile-types-sub-menu">
            <ul class="mobile-types-sub-menu-items">
              <li>test-1</li>
              <li>test-2</li>
              <li>test-3</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="mobile-menu-items">The regions</li>
        <li class="mobile-menu-items">Instructors</li>
        <li class="mobile-menu-items">Questions / Answers</li>
        <li class="mobile-menu-items">Contacts</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `hidden` class and use `toggle` function to add or remove it

```js
const myFunction = () => document.getElementById("mob").classList.toggle("hidden");
```

```css
.hamburger {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #f7941e;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

.mobile-menu {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: absolute;
}

.mobile-menu.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.hamburger-container {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-navbar">
  <div class="hamburger-container" onclick="myFunction()">
    <div class="hamburger"></div>
    <div class="hamburger"></div>
    <div class="hamburger"></div>
    <div class="mobile-menu hidden" id="mob">
      <ul class="mobile-menu-container">
        <li class="mobile-menu-items">Home</li>
        <li class="mobile-menu-items">Types Tours
          <div class="mobile-types-sub-menu">
            <ul class="mobile-types-sub-menu-items">
              <li>test-1</li>
              <li>test-2</li>
              <li>test-3</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="mobile-menu-items">The regions</li>
        <li class="mobile-menu-items">Instructors</li>
        <li class="mobile-menu-items">Questions / Answers</li>
        <li class="mobile-menu-items">Contacts</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it is working @Austin G. May I know how it is working for both clicks i mean one click to open and on next click it is hidden. and why we are using const for function name in JS. Thanks

Comment: @RH_Negative sure, excuse my english lol. Doesn't exists "both" clicks. Any click trigger same function. This function search the element with id ``mob``, and apply ``toggle`` method. This method search a class, in this case is ``hidden``, if doesn't exist, then adds it. If it exists, then delete it.

Comment: @RH_Negative and ``const myFunc = () => {}`` is another way to write a function, called ``arrow function``. Looks cleaner to me, and that's because i changed it. If you write ``function myFunction(){ document.getElement... }`` works too

Answer (score 1):

Toggle the class `active` on the `#mob` element, adding the CSS attributes you added in your function.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const toggle_btn = document.getElementById('mob');
  toggle_btn.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
.hamburger {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #f7941e;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

.mobile-menu {
  display: none;
}

.hamburger-container {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#mob.active {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-navbar">
  <div class="hamburger-container" onclick="myFunction()">
    <div class="hamburger"></div>
    <div class="hamburger"></div>
    <div class="hamburger"></div>
    <div class="mobile-menu" id="mob">
      <ul class="mobile-menu-container">
        <li class="mobile-menu-items">Home</li>
        <li class="mobile-menu-items">Types Tours
          <div class="mobile-types-sub-menu">
            <ul class="mobile-types-sub-menu-items">
              <li>test-1</li>
              <li>test-2</li>
              <li>test-3</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="mobile-menu-items">The regions</li>
        <li class="mobile-menu-items">Instructors</li>
        <li class="mobile-menu-items">Questions / Answers</li>
        <li class="mobile-menu-items">Contacts</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class of `active-mobile-menu` in the CSS and use the `classList.toggle()` function in the JavaScript to switch between different classes.

```js
function myFunction() {
     let mobileMenu = document.getElementById('mob');
    mobileMenu.classList.toggle('active-mobile-menu');
}
```

```css
.hamburger {
            width: 35px;
            height: 5px;
            background-color: #f7941e;
            margin: 6px 0;
        }

        .mobile-menu {
            display: none;
        }

        .active-mobile-menu{
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
        }

        .hamburger-container {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
<div class="mobile-navbar">
        <div class="hamburger-container" onclick="myFunction()">
            <div class="hamburger"></div>
            <div class="hamburger"></div>
            <div class="hamburger"></div>
            <div class="mobile-menu" id="mob">
                <ul class="mobile-menu-container">
                    <li class="mobile-menu-items">Home</li>
                    <li class="mobile-menu-items">Types Tours
                        <div class="mobile-types-sub-menu">
                            <ul class="mobile-types-sub-menu-items">
                                <li>test-1</li>
                                <li>test-2</li>
                                <li>test-3</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="mobile-menu-items">The regions</li>
                    <li class="mobile-menu-items">Instructors</li>
                    <li class="mobile-menu-items">Questions / Answers</li>
                    <li class="mobile-menu-items">Contacts</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**