Close menu when click outside DIV
I need to close menu when clicked outside div on mobile view or when browser is resized.



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">
  <title>Admin Dashboard | Keyframe Effects</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxst.icons8.com/vue-static/landings/line-awesome/line-awesome/1.3.0/css/line-awesome.min.css">
</head>
Style section

<style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather+Sans:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap');
  :root {
    --main-color: #34425A;
    --color-dark: #34425A;
    --text-grey: #B0B0B0;
  }
  
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Merriweather', sans-serif;
  }
  
  #menu-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 165px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: #d6eaf8;
    transition: left 300ms;
  }
  
  .side-menu ul li:hover {
    background-color: #1b4f72;
  }
  
  .side-menu a {
    color: #555;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  
  .side-menu a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    /* Change menu hover text color here */
  }
  
  .side-header {
    background-color: #2471a3;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .side-header h3,
  side-head span {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
  
  .side-content {
    padding: 2rem 0rem;
    height: calc(100vh - 60px);
    overflow: auto;
  }
  /* width */
  
  .side-content::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
  }
  /* Track */
  
  .side-content::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  /* Handle */
  
  .side-content::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #b0b0b0;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  /* Handle on hover */
  
  .side-content::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #b30000;
  }
  
  .sidebar {
    /*overflow-y: auto;*/
  }
  
  .side-menu ul {
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .side-menu a {
    display: block;
    padding: 1rem 0rem;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  .side-menu a.active {
    background: #1b4f72;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #d6eaf8;
  }
  
  .side-menu a.active span,
  .side-menu a.active small {
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .side-menu a span {
    min-height: 15px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    margin: 0rem 0.5rem 0rem 0.5rem !important;
  }
  
  .side-menu a small {
    font-size: 0.95rem;
    /* Sidebar font size */
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0rem 1rem 0rem 1rem !important;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  }
  
  #menu-toggle:checked~.sidebar {
    width: 60px;
  }
  
  #menu-toggle:checked~.sidebar .side-header span {
    display: none;
  }
  
  #menu-toggle:checked~.main-content {
    margin-left: 60px;
    width: calc(100% - 60px);
  }
  
  #menu-toggle:checked~.main-content header {
    left: 60px;
  }
  
  #menu-toggle:checked~.sidebar .profile,
  #menu-toggle:checked~.sidebar .side-menu a small {
    display: none;
  }
  
  #menu-toggle:checked~.sidebar .side-menu a {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    padding: 0.7rem 0rem 0.7rem 0rem;
    /* control menu height here */
    text-align: center;
    /* control toggle menu icons align here center, left or right */
  }
  
  #menu-toggle:checked~.sidebar .side-menu a span {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
  }
  
  .main-content {
    margin-left: 165px;
    width: calc(100% - 165px);
    transition: margin-left 300ms;
  }
  
  header {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 165px;
    z-index: 100;
    height: 60px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -5px rgb(0 0 0 /10%);
    background-color: #2471a3;
    transition: left 300ms;
  }
  
  .header-content,
  .header-menu {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .header-content {
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 1rem 1rem;
    color: #fff!important;
  }
  
  .header-content label:first-child span {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
  }
  
  .header-content label {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .header-menu {
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding-top: .5rem;
  }
  
  .page-content {
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 1.3rem 1rem;
    background: #f1f4f9;
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    .sidebar {
      left: -165px;
      z-index: 90;
    }
    header {
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .main-content {
      margin-left: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    #menu-toggle:checked~.sidebar {
      left: 0;
    }
    #menu-toggle:checked~.sidebar {
      width: 165px;
    }
    #menu-toggle:checked~.sidebar .side-header span {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    #menu-toggle:checked~.sidebar .profile,
    #menu-toggle:checked~.sidebar .side-menu a small {
      display: block;
    }
    #menu-toggle:checked~.sidebar .side-menu a span {
      font-size: 1.7rem;
    }
    #menu-toggle:checked~.main-content header {
      left: 0px;
    }
  }
</style>


<body>
  <input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="side-header">
      <h3>L<span>ogo</span></h3>
    </div>

    <div class="side-content">
      <p></p>
      <div class="side-menu">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="" class="active">
              <span class="las la-home"><small>Dashboard</small></span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">
              <span class="las la-user-alt"><small>Profile</small></span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">
              <span class="las la-envelope"><small>Mailbox</small></span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">
              <span class="las la-clipboard-list"><small>Projects</small></span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">
              <span class="las la-shopping-cart"><small>Orders</small></span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">
              <span class="las la-tasks"><small>Tasks</small></span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="main-content">

    <header>
      <div class="header-content">
        <label for="menu-toggle">
                    <span class="las la-bars"></span>
                </label>
      </div>
    </header>


    <main>

      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        <small>Home / Dashboard</small>
      </div>

      <div class="page-content">

        Page content goes here...

      </div>

    </main>

  </div>
</body>



To see changes go to Mobile view or Resize browser, then open Menu and click outside, it is not closing.
Please help me do this.
May be i need to add JavaScript code
I have tried to resolve this but failed, i wish someone may help.

This answer should help you out... https://stackoverflow.com/a/74602895/1533592

It;s not helping me

This answer should help you. It's using the method of detecting the closest parent of same class as your container in order to detect if to close or not.

@ITgoldman still not helping me, but thanks

Well well. They made a hacky trick, making the menu button be a label for a checkbox. The checkbox rules if it's :checked govern the style of the side menu.
Now all it takes is to detect if a click was inside the .page-content and if so, uncheck the menu button checkbox. It worked when on the correct screen width (mobile).
However, on other display width, the :checked state behaves the opposite of the desired effect. That's why I check first the window.innerWidth.


document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  var elem = event.target;
  var closest = elem.closest(".page-content");

  if (window.innerWidth <= 480) {
    if (closest) {
      // hide menu
      document.getElementById("menu-toggle").checked = false
    }
  }
})
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">
  <title>Admin Dashboard | Keyframe Effects</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxst.icons8.com/vue-static/landings/line-awesome/line-awesome/1.3.0/css/line-awesome.min.css">
</head>
Style section

<style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather+Sans:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap');
   :root {
    --main-color: #34425A;
    --color-dark: #34425A;
    --text-grey: #B0B0B0;
  }
  
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Merriweather', sans-serif;
  }
  
  #menu-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 165px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: #d6eaf8;
    transition: left 300ms;
  }
  
  .side-menu ul li:hover {
    background-color: #1b4f72;
  }
  
  .side-menu a {
    color: #555;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  
  .side-menu a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    /* Change menu hover text color here */
  }
  
  .side-header {
    background-color: #2471a3;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .side-header h3,
  side-head span {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
  
  .side-content {
    padding: 2rem 0rem;
    height: calc(100vh - 60px);
    overflow: auto;
  }
  /* width */
  
  .side-content::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
  }
  /* Track */
  
  .side-content::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  /* Handle */
  
  .side-content::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #b0b0b0;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  /* Handle on hover */
  
  .side-content::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #b30000;
  }
  
  .sidebar {
    /*overflow-y: auto;*/
  }
  
  .side-menu ul {
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .side-menu a {
    display: block;
    padding: 1rem 0rem;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  .side-menu a.active {
    background: #1b4f72;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #d6eaf8;
  }
  
  .side-menu a.active span,
  .side-menu a.active small {
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .side-menu a span {
    min-height: 15px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    margin: 0rem 0.5rem 0rem 0.5rem !important;
  }
  
  .side-menu a small {
    font-size: 0.95rem;
    /* Sidebar font size */
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0rem 1rem 0rem 1rem !important;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  }
  
  #menu-toggle:checked~.sidebar {
    width: 60px;
  }
  
  #menu-toggle:checked~.sidebar .side-header span {
    display: none;
  }
  
  #menu-toggle:checked~.main-content {
    margin-left: 60px;
    width: calc(100% - 60px);
  }
  
  #menu-toggle:checked~.main-content header {
    left: 60px;
  }
  
  #menu-toggle:checked~.sidebar .profile,
  #menu-toggle:checked~.sidebar .side-menu a small {
    display: none;
  }
  
  #menu-toggle:checked~.sidebar .side-menu a {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    padding: 0.7rem 0rem 0.7rem 0rem;
    /* control menu height here */
    text-align: center;
    /* control toggle menu icons align here center, left or right */
  }
  
  #menu-toggle:checked~.sidebar .side-menu a span {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
  }
  
  .main-content {
    margin-left: 165px;
    width: calc(100% - 165px);
    transition: margin-left 300ms;
  }
  
  header {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 165px;
    z-index: 100;
    height: 60px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -5px rgb(0 0 0 /10%);
    background-color: #2471a3;
    transition: left 300ms;
  }
  
  .header-content,
  .header-menu {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .header-content {
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 1rem 1rem;
    color: #fff!important;
  }
  
  .header-content label:first-child span {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
  }
  
  .header-content label {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .header-menu {
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding-top: .5rem;
  }
  
  .page-content {
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 1.3rem 1rem;
    background: #f1f4f9;
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    .sidebar {
      left: -165px;
      z-index: 90;
    }
    header {
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .main-content {
      margin-left: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    #menu-toggle:checked~.sidebar {
      left: 0;
    }
    #menu-toggle:checked~.sidebar {
      width: 165px;
    }
    #menu-toggle:checked~.sidebar .side-header span {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    #menu-toggle:checked~.sidebar .profile,
    #menu-toggle:checked~.sidebar .side-menu a small {
      display: block;
    }
    #menu-toggle:checked~.sidebar .side-menu a span {
      font-size: 1.7rem;
    }
    #menu-toggle:checked~.main-content header {
      left: 0px;
    }
  }
</style>


<body>
  <input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="side-header">
      <h3>L<span>ogo</span></h3>
    </div>

    <div class="side-content">
      <p></p>
      <div class="side-menu">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="" class="active">
              <span class="las la-home"><small>Dashboard</small></span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">
              <span class="las la-user-alt"><small>Profile</small></span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">
              <span class="las la-envelope"><small>Mailbox</small></span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">
              <span class="las la-clipboard-list"><small>Projects</small></span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">
              <span class="las la-shopping-cart"><small>Orders</small></span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">
              <span class="las la-tasks"><small>Tasks</small></span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="main-content">

    <header>
      <div class="header-content">
        <label for="menu-toggle">
                    <span class="las la-bars"></span>
                </label>
      </div>
    </header>


    <main>

      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        <small>Home / Dashboard</small>
      </div>

      <div class="page-content">

        Page content goes here...

      </div>

    </main>

  </div>
</body>




Thanks, you are live saver, this is what i wanted
